# Not enough space to display Admob ad warning

Tags: android, android-layout, admob

I want to put my admob ad on bottom of the parent for all activities.But its showing this error in some of the cases.

```
W/Ads(13240): Not enough space to show ad! Wants: <240, 37>, Has: <240, 0>
```

My **XML** code is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        style="@style/padding_title"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_title" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Tickets &amp; Cards"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="18.0sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </LinearLayout>

     <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
     <More items here>
      </ScrollView>

    <include layout="@layout/ad_container" />

</LinearLayout>
```

And **ad_container.xml** is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
    android:id="@+id/linear_layout_adv_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <com.google.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="a15xxxxxxa8088"
        ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"
        ads:testDevices="TEST_EMULATOR, TEST_DEVICE_ID" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I don't know what am I missing and why is it getting 0 height instead of required one.I hope someone points out the problem.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your outer layout has height `match_parent`. That means it's the size of the window. All of its children have height `wrap_content` meaning each fits to the height of the respective content. If the height of the content of all the preceding children (your ad unit is last after all) adds up to more than the window height, there's no room left for the ad unit.

Comment: So What should I do to make it appear at bottom?

Comment: Set it to 37 pixels, insted of wrap_content.